# commands.py: name 'play_command' is not defined

Tags: gwt, playframework

I am new to Play and GWT and following the documentation given [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/gwt). But I see the following errors:

```
bash-3.2$ play deps test-gwt

!! Error whileloading /opt/play-1.2.1/modules/gwt-1.0/commands.py: name 'play_command' is not defined  
~
~ Resolving dependencies using /Users/Harit/Documents/personal/projects/test-gwt/conf/dependencies.yml,  
~
~   play->gwt 1.0 (from playLocalModules)  
~
~ Installing resolved dependencies,   
~
~   modules/gwt-1.0 -> /opt/play-1.2.1/modules/gwt-1.0  
~
~ Done!
```

I see that there is a corresponding bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/play/+bug/558412), and status is `fix_commited`, but I don't know what shall I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just because play-gwt module is not compatible with play 1.2 ?
Apparently this module is quite old and not very active and command syntax has changed in version 1.1.x or something like that.

Before, you wrote commands.py like that:

```
...
if play_command.startswith('gwt:'):
...
```

and now, it is like that:

```
...
MODULE = "secure"

COMMANDS = ["secure:", "secure:ov", "secure:override"]

HELP = {
    "secure:": "Show help for the secure module",
    "secure:override": "Override the CSS, login or layout"
}

def execute(**kargs):
    command = kargs.get("command")
    app = kargs.get("app")
    args = kargs.get("args")
    env = kargs.get("env")

    if command == 'secure:':
...
```

In my opinion, the modification is really light so you can either ask the module owner if he would accept to do it or even do it by yourself ;)

There is also a GWT2 module which seems much more active: http://www.playframework.org/modules/gwt2 (apparently no new version since last october but the github project shows very recent commits with play1.2 support)